# What is the best practice for overriding values in helm subcharts on a per-cluster basis?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, configuration-management, kubernetes-helm

First, a little context: I have 4 Kubernetes clusters, one for each environment (develop, staging, testing, prod). Each cluster has its own `values.yaml` file with env-specific configuration of all helm charts that we've written.

So, when our CD pipeline deploys `mychart` to the `develop` cluster, it essentially does the following:

`helm install -f base-values.yaml -f develop-values.yaml ./mychart.tgz`

Now, let's presume `mychart` has a `requirements.yaml` file which specifies [the mongodb chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb) as a subchart dependency. The mongodb chart references, for example, `.Values.mongodbRootPassword`. When included as a subchart by `mychart`, I can set `.Values.mongodb.mongodbRootPassword` in `mychart`'s default `values.yaml` to change this value.

My problem is that given my current CD pipeline, if I set `.Values.mongodb.mongodbRootPassword` in `develop-values.yaml`, it will be taken for *all* mongodb instances that are deployed to the `develop` cluster - not just `mychart`'s.

So, my questions:

- using per-environment `values.yaml` files, how would I go about setting `mychart`'s mongodb's root password in one of the cluster-specific `values.yaml` files?
- is this even possible? Or is my current CD approach (per-environment values files) an anti-pattern?
- if this is not possible or an anti-pattern, how would you go about setting the values of helm individual charts and subcharts on a per-environment basis?

Answer (score 3):

> - using per-environment `values.yaml` files, how would I go about setting `mychart`'s mongodb's root password in one of the cluster-specific `values.yaml` files?

You can override YAML files with [`--set`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts.md#using-the-cli-with-tags-and-conditions) option from `install`

**Example:**

`helm install -f base-values.yaml -f develop-values.yaml --set someSection.someValue=1234 ./mychart.tgz`

Then, you can set CI command call with environment settings and have just one YAML.

> - is this even possible? Or is my current CD approach (per-environment values files) an anti-pattern?

Nope, that's a feature :-)

> - if this is not possible or an anti-pattern, how would you go about setting the values of helm individual charts and subcharts on a per-environment basis?

It would be nice also. Perhaps, if your infrastructure grow fast and you have a lot of environments, apps or else, this could be better to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I created a named template (within _helpers.tpl) that combined a set of default values defined in values.yaml with a set of env specific values defined in their own file. This allows me to set 20+ default values and then override them with the env file WITHOUT setting them as part of the cli command. I wanted to avoid using the cli to override values because that gets complicated and doesn't provide tracking (ie my env specific files are in git).

Comment: Could you edit your answer to provide some example code, or link to the repo in question? Thanks!